# How to install tomcat for many instances with CHEF?

Tags: linux, tomcat, chef, tomcat6, tomcat7

I would like to install tomcat with a `recipe` through `chef` at some folder, like `/company/tomcat6.0.45-port8081`. But sometimes I have many instances of tomcat, like `/company/tomcat7.0.41-port8082`, `/company/tomcat7.0.39-port8083` and go on, how can I do that ?

Any idea ?

Comment: I install my tomcat with a script, to ensure that the configuration files won't be always the same, 'cause they change with every version, and then, defined at `chef` to mantain my folder structure, permissions from users and groups only. But I wonder if this is a good approach.

Comment: EEAA was asking you to post some of your configuration scripts, btw ;)

Comment: Have a look at [RiotGames' `artifact_deploy` resource](https://github.com/RiotGames/artifact-cookbook).  Deploying Tomcat with that, you can specify different `deploy_to` locations. It's quite powerful.  You'd have to ditch the tomcat cookbook though and handle the Tomcat configuration on your own.

Answer (score 1):

I create a recipe in chef, which you just define the role for which server you put this role, and it will install many tomcat instances in different port, for you.

```
Recipe : tomcat
```

**attributes**

```
default['tomcat']['default']['port']  = "8081"
```

**files/default/catalina.sh**

```
// this catalina.sh differs only with the JDK path inside of` it.
#!/bin/sh

# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Start/Stop Script for the CATALINA Server
#
# Environment Variable Prerequisites
#
#   CATALINA_HOME   May point at your Catalina "build" directory.
#
#   CATALINA_BASE   (Optional) Base directory for resolving dynamic portions
#                   of a Catalina installation.  If not present, resolves to
#                   the same directory that CATALINA_HOME points to.
#
#   CATALINA_OUT    (Optional) Full path to a file where stdout and stderr
#                   will be redirected.
#                   Default is $CATALINA_BASE/logs/catalina.out
#
#   CATALINA_OPTS   (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "start",
#                   or "run" command is executed.
#
#   CATALINA_TMPDIR (Optional) Directory path location of temporary directory
#                   the JVM should use (java.io.tmpdir).  Defaults to
#                   $CATALINA_BASE/temp.
#
#   JAVA_HOME       Must point at your Java Development Kit installation.
#                   Required to run the with the "debug" argument.
#
#   JRE_HOME        Must point at your Java Development Kit installation.
#                   Defaults to JAVA_HOME if empty.
#
#   JAVA_OPTS       (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "start",
#                   "stop", or "run" command is executed.
#
#   JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS (Optional) Lists of of colon separated directories
#                   containing some jars in order to allow replacement of APIs
#                   created outside of the JCP (i.e. DOM and SAX from W3C).
#                   It can also be used to update the XML parser implementation.
#                   Defaults to $CATALINA_HOME/endorsed.
#
#   JPDA_TRANSPORT  (Optional) JPDA transport used when the "jpda start"
#                   command is executed. The default is "dt_socket".
#
#   JPDA_ADDRESS    (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "jpda start"
#                   command is executed. The default is 8000.
#
#   JPDA_SUSPEND    (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "jpda start"
#                   command is executed. Specifies whether JVM should suspend
#                   execution immediately after startup. Default is "n".
#
#   JPDA_OPTS       (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "jpda start"
#                   command is executed. If used, JPDA_TRANSPORT, JPDA_ADDRESS,
#                   and JPDA_SUSPEND are ignored. Thus, all required jpda
#                   options MUST be specified. The default is:
#
#                   -agentlib:jdwp=transport=$JPDA_TRANSPORT,
#                       address=$JPDA_ADDRESS,server=y,suspend=$JPDA_SUSPEND
#
#   CATALINA_PID    (Optional) Path of the file which should contains the pid
#                   of catalina startup java process, when start (fork) is used
#
#   LOGGING_CONFIG  (Optional) Override Tomcat's logging config file
#                   Example (all one line)
#                   LOGGING_CONFIG="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties"
#
#   LOGGING_MANAGER (Optional) Override Tomcat's logging manager
#                   Example (all one line)
#                   LOGGING_MANAGER="-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"
#
# $Id: catalina.sh 1146097 2011-07-13 15:25:05Z markt $
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# OS specific support.  $var _must_ be set to either true or false.
cygwin=false
os400=false
darwin=false
case "`uname`" in
CYGWIN*) cygwin=true;;
OS400*) os400=true;;
Darwin*) darwin=true;;
esac

JAVA_HOME=/company/jdk6
JRE_HOME=/company/jdk6/jre

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS ""-Xms2048m ""-Xmx2048m ""-Dsun.jnu.encoding=ISO-8859-1 ""-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 ""-XX:MaxPermSize=256m ""-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled ""-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"

# resolve links - $0 may be a softlink
PRG="$0"

while [ -h "$PRG" ]; do
  ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`
  link=`expr "$ls" : '.*-> \(.*\)$'`
  if expr "$link" : '/.*' > /dev/null; then
    PRG="$link"
  else
    PRG=`dirname "$PRG"`/"$link"
  fi
done

# Get standard environment variables
PRGDIR=`dirname "$PRG"`

# Only set CATALINA_HOME if not already set
[ -z "$CATALINA_HOME" ] && CATALINA_HOME=`cd "$PRGDIR/.." >/dev/null; pwd`

# Copy CATALINA_BASE from CATALINA_HOME if not already set
[ -z "$CATALINA_BASE" ] && CATALINA_BASE="$CATALINA_HOME"

# Ensure that any user defined CLASSPATH variables are not used on startup,
# but allow them to be specified in setenv.sh, in rare case when it is needed.
CLASSPATH=

if [ -r "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh" ]; then
  . "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh"
elif [ -r "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh" ]; then
  . "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh"
fi

# For Cygwin, ensure paths are in UNIX format before anything is touched
if $cygwin; then
  [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] && JAVA_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$JAVA_HOME"`
  [ -n "$JRE_HOME" ] && JRE_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$JRE_HOME"`
  [ -n "$CATALINA_HOME" ] && CATALINA_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$CATALINA_HOME"`
  [ -n "$CATALINA_BASE" ] && CATALINA_BASE=`cygpath --unix "$CATALINA_BASE"`
  [ -n "$CLASSPATH" ] && CLASSPATH=`cygpath --path --unix "$CLASSPATH"`
fi

# For OS400
if $os400; then
  # Set job priority to standard for interactive (interactive - 6) by using
  # the interactive priority - 6, the helper threads that respond to requests
  # will be running at the same priority as interactive jobs.
  COMMAND='chgjob job('$JOBNAME') runpty(6)'
  system $COMMAND

  # Enable multi threading
  export QIBM_MULTI_THREADED=Y
fi

# Get standard Java environment variables
if $os400; then
  # -r will Only work on the os400 if the files are:
  # 1. owned by the user
  # 2. owned by the PRIMARY group of the user
  # this will not work if the user belongs in secondary groups
  BASEDIR="$CATALINA_HOME"
  . "$CATALINA_HOME"/bin/setclasspath.sh
else
  if [ -r "$CATALINA_HOME"/bin/setclasspath.sh ]; then
    BASEDIR="$CATALINA_HOME"
    . "$CATALINA_HOME"/bin/setclasspath.sh
  else
    echo "Cannot find $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setclasspath.sh"
    echo "This file is needed to run this program"
    exit 1
  fi
fi

if [ -z "$CATALINA_BASE" ] ; then
  CATALINA_BASE="$CATALINA_HOME"
fi

# Add tomcat-juli.jar and bootstrap.jar to classpath
# tomcat-juli.jar can be over-ridden per instance
if [ ! -z "$CLASSPATH" ] ; then
  CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH":
fi
if [ "$CATALINA_BASE" != "$CATALINA_HOME" ] && [ -r "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/tomcat-juli.jar" ] ; then
  CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH""$CATALINA_BASE"/bin/tomcat-juli.jar:"$CATALINA_HOME"/bin/bootstrap.jar
else
  CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH""$CATALINA_HOME"/bin/bootstrap.jar
fi

if [ -z "$CATALINA_OUT" ] ; then
  CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out
fi

if [ -z "$CATALINA_TMPDIR" ] ; then
  # Define the java.io.tmpdir to use for Catalina
  CATALINA_TMPDIR="$CATALINA_BASE"/temp
fi

# Bugzilla 37848: When no TTY is available, don't output to console
have_tty=0
if [ "`tty`" != "not a tty" ]; then
    have_tty=1
fi

# For Cygwin, switch paths to Windows format before running java
if $cygwin; then
  JAVA_HOME=`cygpath --absolute --windows "$JAVA_HOME"`
  JRE_HOME=`cygpath --absolute --windows "$JRE_HOME"`
  CATALINA_HOME=`cygpath --absolute --windows "$CATALINA_HOME"`
  CATALINA_BASE=`cygpath --absolute --windows "$CATALINA_BASE"`
  CATALINA_TMPDIR=`cygpath --absolute --windows "$CATALINA_TMPDIR"`
  CLASSPATH=`cygpath --path --windows "$CLASSPATH"`
  JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS=`cygpath --path --windows "$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS"`
fi

# Set juli LogManager config file if it is present and an override has not been issued
if [ -z "$LOGGING_CONFIG" ]; then
  if [ -r "$CATALINA_BASE"/conf/logging.properties ]; then
    LOGGING_CONFIG="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties"
  else
    # Bugzilla 45585
    LOGGING_CONFIG="-Dnop"
  fi
fi

if [ -z "$LOGGING_MANAGER" ]; then
  JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"
else
  JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS $LOGGING_MANAGER"
fi

# ----- Execute The Requested Command -----------------------------------------

# Bugzilla 37848: only output this if we have a TTY
if [ $have_tty -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "Using CATALINA_BASE:   $CATALINA_BASE"
  echo "Using CATALINA_HOME:   $CATALINA_HOME"
  echo "Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: $CATALINA_TMPDIR"
  if [ "$1" = "debug" ] ; then
    echo "Using JAVA_HOME:       $JAVA_HOME"
  else
    echo "Using JRE_HOME:        $JRE_HOME"
  fi
  echo "Using CLASSPATH:       $CLASSPATH"
  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
    echo "Using CATALINA_PID:    $CATALINA_PID"
  fi
fi

if [ "$1" = "jpda" ] ; then
  if [ -z "$JPDA_TRANSPORT" ]; then
    JPDA_TRANSPORT="dt_socket"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_ADDRESS" ]; then
    JPDA_ADDRESS="8000"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_SUSPEND" ]; then
    JPDA_SUSPEND="n"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_OPTS" ]; then
    JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=$JPDA_TRANSPORT,address=$JPDA_ADDRESS,server=y,suspend=$JPDA_SUSPEND"
  fi
  CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS $JPDA_OPTS"
  shift
fi

if [ "$1" = "debug" ] ; then
  if $os400; then
    echo "Debug command not available on OS400"
    exit 1
  else
    shift
    if [ "$1" = "-security" ] ; then
      if [ $have_tty -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "Using Security Manager"
      fi
      shift
      exec "$_RUNJDB" "$LOGGING_CONFIG" $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
        -Djava.endorsed.dirs="$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" \
        -sourcepath "$CATALINA_HOME"/../../java \
        -Djava.security.manager \
        -Djava.security.policy=="$CATALINA_BASE"/conf/catalina.policy \
        -Dcatalina.base="$CATALINA_BASE" \
        -Dcatalina.home="$CATALINA_HOME" \
        -Djava.io.tmpdir="$CATALINA_TMPDIR" \
        org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start
    else
      exec "$_RUNJDB" "$LOGGING_CONFIG" $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
        -Djava.endorsed.dirs="$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" \
        -sourcepath "$CATALINA_HOME"/../../java \
        -Dcatalina.base="$CATALINA_BASE" \
        -Dcatalina.home="$CATALINA_HOME" \
        -Djava.io.tmpdir="$CATALINA_TMPDIR" \
        org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start
    fi
  fi

elif [ "$1" = "run" ]; then

  shift
  if [ "$1" = "-security" ] ; then
    if [ $have_tty -eq 1 ]; then
      echo "Using Security Manager"
    fi
    shift
    exec "$_RUNJAVA" "$LOGGING_CONFIG" $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
      -Djava.endorsed.dirs="$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" \
      -Djava.security.manager \
      -Djava.security.policy=="$CATALINA_BASE"/conf/catalina.policy \
      -Dcatalina.base="$CATALINA_BASE" \
      -Dcatalina.home="$CATALINA_HOME" \
      -Djava.io.tmpdir="$CATALINA_TMPDIR" \
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start
  else
    exec "$_RUNJAVA" "$LOGGING_CONFIG" $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
      -Djava.endorsed.dirs="$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" \
      -Dcatalina.base="$CATALINA_BASE" \
      -Dcatalina.home="$CATALINA_HOME" \
      -Djava.io.tmpdir="$CATALINA_TMPDIR" \
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start
  fi

elif [ "$1" = "start" ] ; then

  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
    if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
      if [ -s "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
        echo "Existing PID file found during start."
        if [ -r "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
          PID=`cat "$CATALINA_PID"`
          ps -p $PID >/dev/null 2>&1
          if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
            echo "Tomcat appears to still be running with PID $PID. Start aborted."
            exit 1
          else
            echo "Removing/clearing stale PID file."
            rm -f "$CATALINA_PID" >/dev/null 2>&1
            if [ $? != 0 ]; then
              if [ -w "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
                cat /dev/null > "$CATALINA_PID"
              else
                echo "Unable to remove or clear stale PID file. Start aborted."
                exit 1
              fi
            fi
          fi
        else
          echo "Unable to read PID file. Start aborted."
          exit 1
        fi
      else
        rm -f "$CATALINA_PID" >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? != 0 ]; then
          if [ ! -w "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
            echo "Unable to remove or write to empty PID file. Start aborted."
            exit 1
          fi
        fi
      fi
    fi
  fi

  shift
  touch "$CATALINA_OUT"
  if [ "$1" = "-security" ] ; then
    if [ $have_tty -eq 1 ]; then
      echo "Using Security Manager"
    fi
    shift
    "$_RUNJAVA" "$LOGGING_CONFIG" $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
      -Djava.endorsed.dirs="$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" \
      -Djava.security.manager \
      -Djava.security.policy=="$CATALINA_BASE"/conf/catalina.policy \
      -Dcatalina.base="$CATALINA_BASE" \
      -Dcatalina.home="$CATALINA_HOME" \
      -Djava.io.tmpdir="$CATALINA_TMPDIR" \
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start \
      >> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 &

  else
    "$_RUNJAVA" "$LOGGING_CONFIG" $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
      -Djava.endorsed.dirs="$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" \
      -Dcatalina.base="$CATALINA_BASE" \
      -Dcatalina.home="$CATALINA_HOME" \
      -Djava.io.tmpdir="$CATALINA_TMPDIR" \
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start \
      >> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 &

  fi

  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
    echo $! > "$CATALINA_PID"
  fi

elif [ "$1" = "stop" ] ; then

  shift

  SLEEP=5
  if [ ! -z "$1" ]; then
    echo $1 | grep "[^0-9]" >/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
      SLEEP=$1
      shift
    fi
  fi

  FORCE=0
  if [ "$1" = "-force" ]; then
    shift
    FORCE=1
  fi

  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
    if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
      if [ -s "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
        kill -0 `cat "$CATALINA_PID"` >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
          echo "PID file found but no matching process was found. Stop aborted."
          exit 1
        fi
      else
        echo "PID file is empty and has been ignored."
      fi
    else
      echo "\$CATALINA_PID was set but the specified file does not exist. Is Tomcat running? Stop aborted."
      exit 1
    fi
  fi

  "$_RUNJAVA" $JAVA_OPTS \
    -Djava.endorsed.dirs="$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" \
    -Dcatalina.base="$CATALINA_BASE" \
    -Dcatalina.home="$CATALINA_HOME" \
    -Djava.io.tmpdir="$CATALINA_TMPDIR" \
    org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" stop

  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
    if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
      while [ $SLEEP -ge 0 ]; do
        kill -0 `cat "$CATALINA_PID"` >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
          rm -f "$CATALINA_PID" >/dev/null 2>&1
          if [ $? != 0 ]; then
            if [ -w "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
              cat /dev/null > "$CATALINA_PID"
            else
              echo "Tomcat stopped but the PID file could not be removed or cleared."
            fi
          fi
          break
        fi
        if [ $SLEEP -gt 0 ]; then
          sleep 1
        fi
        if [ $SLEEP -eq 0 ]; then
          if [ $FORCE -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Tomcat did not stop in time. PID file was not removed."
          fi
        fi
        SLEEP=`expr $SLEEP - 1 `
      done
    fi
  fi

  if [ $FORCE -eq 1 ]; then
    if [ -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
      echo "Kill failed: \$CATALINA_PID not set"
    else
      if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
        PID=`cat "$CATALINA_PID"`
        echo "Killing Tomcat with the PID: $PID"
        kill -9 $PID
        rm -f "$CATALINA_PID" >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? != 0 ]; then
          echo "Tomcat was killed but the PID file could not be removed."
        fi
      fi
    fi
  fi

elif [ "$1" = "version" ] ; then

    "$_RUNJAVA"   \
      -classpath "$CATALINA_HOME/lib/catalina.jar" \
      org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo

else

  echo "Usage: catalina.sh ( commands ... )"
  echo "commands:"
  if $os400; then
    echo "  debug             Start Catalina in a debugger (not available on OS400)"
    echo "  debug -security   Debug Catalina with a security manager (not available on OS400)"
  else
    echo "  debug             Start Catalina in a debugger"
    echo "  debug -security   Debug Catalina with a security manager"
  fi
  echo "  jpda start        Start Catalina under JPDA debugger"
  echo "  run               Start Catalina in the current window"
  echo "  run -security     Start in the current window with security manager"
  echo "  start             Start Catalina in a separate window"
  echo "  start -security   Start in a separate window with security manager"
  echo "  stop              Stop Catalina, waiting up to 5 seconds for the process to end"
  echo "  stop n            Stop Catalina, waiting up to n seconds for the process to end"
  echo "  stop -force       Stop Catalina, wait up to 5 seconds and then use kill -KILL if still running"
  echo "  stop n -force     Stop Catalina, wait up to n seconds and then use kill -KILL if still running"
  echo "  version           What version of tomcat are you running?"
  echo "Note: Waiting for the process to end and use of the -force option require that \$CATALINA_PID is defined"
  exit 1

fi
```

**files/default/tomcat-users.xml**

```
<tomcat-users><role rolename="manager-gui"/><role rolename="admin-gui"/><user username="admin" password="tucanoNAj4n3l4" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/></tomcat-users>
```

**recipes/default.rb**

```
#
# Cookbook Name:: tomcat-ii
# Recipe:: default
#
# Copyright 2013, company.com
#
# All rights reserved - Do Not Redistribute
#

return if tagged?('norun::tomcat-ii')

user "tomcat" do
    system true
end

bash "download_tomcat_6" do
  user "root"
  code <<-EOH
  cd /company/inst-files/
  if [ ! -f /company/inst-files/tomcat-6.tar.gz ]; then
    wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/company-backup/infra/linux/software/tomcat-6.tar.gz
    tar xzvf tomcat-6.tar.gz -C /company/inst-files/
  fi
  EOH
end

node['tomcat']['port'].each do |port|
  directory "/company/tomcat-6-port-#{port}" do
    owner "tomcat"
    group "tomcat"
    mode 00755
    action :create
  end

  directory "/company-logs/tomcat-6-port-#{port}/old" do
    owner "tomcat"
    group "tomcat"
    mode 00755
    action :create
    recursive true
  end

  directory "/company/tomcat-6-port-#{port}/webapps" do
    owner "tomcat"
    group "tomcat_admin"
    mode 00755
    action :nothing
    recursive true
  end

  bash "install_tomcat_6" do
    user "root"
    code <<-EOH
    if [ ! -d "/company/tomcat-6-port-#{port}/conf" ]; then
        cd /company/inst-files
        cp -rv tomcat-6/* /company/tomcat-6-port-#{port}/
        rm -rf /company/tomcat-6-port-#{port}/logs
        ln -s /company-logs/tomcat-6-port-#{port}/ /company/tomcat-6-port-#{port}/logs

        port="#{port}"
        echo "$port" > /tmp/port.log
        short_port="${port:2:2}";
        sed 's:<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">:<Server port="'"$short_port"05'" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">:' /company/tomcat-6-port-#{port}/conf/server.xml > /company/temp_server_1.xml;
        sed 's:<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1\.1:<Connector port="'"$port"'" protocol="HTTP/1\.1:' /company/temp_server_1.xml > /company/temp_server_2.xml;
        sed 's:<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1\.3" redirectPort="8443" />:<Connector port="'"$short_port"09'" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="'"$short_port"43'" />":' /company/temp_server_2.xml > /company/temp_server_3.xml;
        sed 's:<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">:<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="'tomcat"$port"'">":' /company/temp_server_3.xml > /company/temp_server_4.xml;
        mv /company/tomcat-6-port-#{port}/conf/server.xml /company/tomcat-6-port-#{port}/conf/server.xml.original;
        mv /company/temp_server_4.xml /company/tomcat-6-port-#{port}/conf/server.xml;
        rm /company/temp_server*;

        /bin/chown tomcat:tomcat /company/tomcat-6-port-#{port}/ -R
        /bin/chown tomcat:tomcat /company-logs/tomcat-6-port-#{port}/ -R
        /bin/chown tomcat:tomcat /company/tomcat-6-port-#{port}/webapps -R
    fi        
    EOH
  end

  execute "set permissions tomcat" do
    command "/bin/chown tomcat:tomcat /company/tomcat-6-port-#{port}/ -R"
    action :run
    only_if do File.exists?("/company/tomcat-6-port-#{port}") end
  end

  execute "set permissions tomcat" do
    command "/bin/chown tomcat:tomcat /company-logs/tomcat-6-port-#{port}/ -R"
    action :run
    only_if do File.exists?("/company-logs/tomcat-6-port-#{port}") end
  end

  execute "set permissions tomcat" do
    command "/bin/chown tomcat:tomcat_admin /company/tomcat-6-port-#{port}/webapps -R"
    action :run
    only_if do File.exists?("/company/tomcat-6-port-#{port}/webapps") end
  end    

  template "/etc/init.d/tomcat-6-port-#{port}" do
    owner "root"
    group "root"
    mode "0755"
    source "tomcat-service.erb"
    variables(
    :port => "#{port}"
    )
  end

  cookbook_file "/company/tomcat-6-port-#{port}/conf/tomcat-users.xml" do
    owner "tomcat"
    group "tomcat"
    mode "0755"
    source "tomcat-users.xml"
  end

  cookbook_file "/company/tomcat-6-port-#{port}/bin/catalina.sh" do
    owner "tomcat"
    group "tomcat"
    mode "0755"
    source "catalina.sh"
  end

  service "tomcat-6-port-#{port}" do
   supports :status => true,
            :start => true,
            :stop => true,
            :restart => true
   action [ :enable, :start ]
  end
end

templates/default/tomcat-service.erb

# This is the init script for starting up the
#  Jakarta Tomcat server
#
# chkconfig: 345 91 10
# description: Starts and stops the Tomcat daemon.
#

# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

# Get config.
. /etc/sysconfig/network

# Check that networking is up.
[ "${NETWORKING}" = "no" ] && exit 0

tomcat=/company/tomcat-6-port-<%= @port %>
startup=$tomcat/bin/startup.sh
shutdown=$tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
export JAVA_HOME=/company/jdk6

start(){

  #move os arquivos de log para os arquivos antigos
  /bin/ls /company-logs/tomcat-6-port-<%= @port %>/*.log > /dev/null  2>&1
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    mv -f /company-logs/tomcat-6-port-<%= @port %>/*.log /company-logs/tomcat-6-port-<%= @port %>/old/
  fi

  #move o catalina.out para os arquivos antigos
  if [ -e /company-logs/tomcat-6-port-<%= @port %>/catalina.out ]; then
    mv -f /company-logs/tomcat-6-port-<%= @port %>/catalina.out /company-logs/tomcat-6-port-<%= @port %>/old/
  fi

  numproc=`ps -ef | grep "/company/tomcat-6-port-<%= @port %>/bin/bootstrap.jar" | grep -v grep |awk -F' ' '{ print $2 }'`;

  if [ $numproc ]; then
    echo "Tomcat <%= @port %> is running!"
    echo "Stop then first!"
  else
    action $"Starting Tomcat <%= @port %> service: " su - tomcat -c $startup
    RETVAL=$?
  fi

}

stop(){
  numproc=`ps -ef | grep "/company/tomcat-6-port-<%= @port %>/bin/bootstrap.jar" | grep -v grep |awk -F' ' '{ print $2 }'`;

  if [ $numproc ]; then
    action $"Stopping Tomcat <%= @port %> service: " $shutdown
    RETVAL=$?
  else
    echo "Tomcat <%= @port %> is not running..."
  fi

  numproc=`ps -ef | grep "/company/tomcat-6-port-<%= @port %>/bin/bootstrap.jar" | grep -v grep |awk -F' ' '{ print $2 }'`;
  if [ $numproc ]; then
    kill -9 $numproc
  fi
}

restart(){
  stop
  start
}

status(){
  numproc=`ps -ef | grep "/company/tomcat-6-port-<%= @port %>/bin/bootstrap.jar" | grep -v grep | wc -l`
  if [ $numproc -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Tomcat is running..."
  else
    echo "Tomcat is stopped..."
  fi
}

# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
start)
 start
 ;;
stop)
 stop
 ;;
status)
 status
 ;;
restart)
 restart
 ;;
*)


    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
     exit 1
    esac

exit 0
```

Then you should just create a role for the server:

**roles/tomcat-server93.rb**

```
name "tomcat-server93"
description "Configuration to tomcat instances"

default_attributes(
  "tomcat" => {
    "port" => [ "8081", "8082", "8083" ]
  }
)

run_list(
  "recipe[tomcat]"
)
```